# C# how do I change the gridlines color in windows.forms.listview

Tags: c#, listview

how do I change the gridlines color in windows.forms.listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a way to do it on a listview without overriding the Paint Event. However, if you are able to switch to a gridview you can do it like so:

```
this.dataGridView1.GridColor = Color.BlueViolet;
```

[REF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ehz9ksfa(VS.80).aspx)